# Recursive(or normal search) search in an Array of hashes using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes in this format and I want to search for the index of a deep element.

`[{:users => [{:admins => [:address, :stage]}]}, :client]` and I want a function that will return the index of an element(like `:stage`)

```
def return_index(array، value)
 return "" #the index even as a string. "[0][:admins][1]". I can use eval to find the index
end
```

Comment: Should your method have a second argument, `value` (e.g., `value #=> :stage`)? When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g, `arr = [{:users=>...]`). That way readers can refer to those variables (here just one) in answers and comments without having to define them, and all readers will reference the same variable. It's also helpful to show your expected or desired result. You may wish to edit your question to do that.

Comment: see breadth first search or depth first search: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109034/breadth-and-depth-first-search-in-ruby

Comment: cary, yes it can have another argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
def return_path(arr, value, path=[])
  ndx = arr.index(value)
  return path + [ndx] unless ndx.nil?
  arr.each_with_index do |o,i|
    next unless o.is_a?(Hash)
    o.each do |k,v|
      next unless v.is_a?(Array)
      path = return_path(v, value, path+[i,k])
      return path unless path.nil?
    end
  end
  nil
end

value = :stage

arr = [{ :users=>[{ :admins=>[:address, :stage] }] }]    
return_path(arr, :stage)
  #=> [0, :users, 0, :admins, 1] 

arr = [{ :users=>[{ :admins=>[:what, { :huh => [:stage, :address] }] }] }]
return_path(arr, :stage)
  #=> [0, :users, 0, :admins, 1, :huh, 0]

arr = [{ :users=>[{ :admins=>[{ :huh => [:name, :address] }, :what ] }] }]
return_path(arr, :stage)
  #=> nil
```

Comment: thnks for the inspiration. I might need to update my question a bit. cause what I really need is the complete index of the value. something like `array[0][:admins][1]`. not just one index.

Comment: I modified the method to return the full path.

Comment: `array  = [{:banana=>[{:apple=>:orange}]}]`. `return_path(array, :banana)` did not give correct result. I get `nil`

Comment: @anyavacy, I assumed the element being searched for is a value in a hash, as it is in the example in your question. In your example in the above comment it is a key (which is why `nil` is returned). Perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: no, I search for the index any possible value in the array. but your code is helping me a lot. i will try to modify it and see if i can manage do that. thnks